# When and why did we start "guessing" so much?

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms

Nowadays it's hard to eavesdrop on an informal conversation (at least in the US) without hearing the phrase 'i guess'.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guess) has two relevant definitions for *guess*:

> (chiefly US) to suppose (introducing a proposition of uncertain plausibility).
>
> (colloquial) To think, conclude, or decide (without a connotation of uncertainty). Usually in first person: "*I guess*".

The earliest quotation they have for the first sense is from Shakespeare, which is far further back in time than I'd expected it to be. (*Not all together; better far, **I guess**, That we do make our entrance several ways.*- [Henry VI](https://www.litcharts.com/shakescleare/shakespeare-translations/henry-vi-part-1/act-2-scene-1))

But I'm less interested in the earliest uses and more interested in when (and also why) it became so prevalent.

---

Responding to a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610135/when-and-why-did-we-start-guessing-so-much?noredirect=1#comment1544153_610135):

> I don't know if the OP has noticed an increase in its use (when, please?) or has always heard it but only just thought to complain.

I've heard it all my (teenage) life and use it myself (so not a complaint). There's not really a specific uptick I've witnessed, but I doubt that people 200 years ago were going around and 'guessing' instead of 'thinking'.

Comment: As for the earliest uses, [the paywalled OED’s earliest reference for *I guess*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82251) used in this sense is not Shakespeare but John Locke in 1692. The sense given is:  “6. ***I guess***: sometimes used, with playful moderation of statement, in reference to what the speaker regards as a fact or a secure inference. Hence *colloquial*, originally in the *northern U.S.* (sometimes with omission of the pronoun) = ‘I am pretty sure’.” ―Which leads me to postulate that the corresponding *southern U.S.* phrasing might be ***I reckon***.

Comment: @tchrist: It's not obvious to me that ***guess, reckon*** are any particular kind of "special case" as distinct from other words we might use in exactly the same contexts with exactly the same meaning *(**imagine, suppose, think, expect, bet,...**)*. Dialectally, I think also ***calculate***, in some contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Dincha know yarnt sposta guess? :) But yes, there's some degree of distancing present here in conversation, no matter the specific verb used.

Comment: Found one! [*“I **calculate**," said Sam, entering, "that you ain't the only inhabitant of this location.” “I **reckon not**,” was the reply...*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+calculate+said+sam%22&biw=1536&bih=747&tbm=bks&ei=_iK0ZIPyBa23hbIPoO-uQA&ved=0ahUKEwiD6cbX2pOAAxWtW0EAHaC3Cwg4ChDh1QMICQ&uact=5&oq=%22I+calculate+said+sam%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhYiSSBjYWxjdWxhdGUgc2FpZCBzYW0iSMIXUKMIWLcScAB4AJABAJgBZKAB-AKqAQM0LjG4AQPIAQD4AQGIBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) But I think we can take it for granted the one *replying* knew for sure that there were ***in fact*** other inhabitants!

Comment: ***My*** "guess" is that people have been using circumlocutory verbs in relation to what they know/think since long before even the *earliest* "English". I also reckon this happens in *every* language.

Comment: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED18464/track?counter=1&search_id=26385924   Late 14th c.   **Guess** is not formal. **suppose** is sorta formal.

Comment: I imagine it's more common in casual speech/texting than in formal written English, and since today we have a lot more of the casual than the formal, it will seem to increase over the long term. I don't know if the OP has noticed an increase in its use (when, please?) or has always heard it but only just thought to complain, but I'm sure it has a long history and before it people were saying other equally annoying things (and you can compare alternatives like "I reckon" in parts of the US South.) So good news: it doesn't reflect a decline in logical rigor!

Comment: For what it is worth, Ngram shows a spike in usage from the 90s. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guess&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @FumbleFingers Another option is "figure", which has a similar meaning to "reckon" and "calculate".

Comment: ***It's not obvious to me, My "guess" is, I imagine it's, For what it is worth,...*** Half the comments here start with *some* kind of "hedge", which at the end of the day is mostly what initial ***I guess...*** amounts to.

Comment: "I guess" at the start of sentences often undergoes conversational deletion, as in "guess we showed up too late." I think that this usage of "guess" may be turning into a discourse marker of sorts.

Comment: Your question starts by separating two senses of the word, but it is not clear how that distinction informs the punchline of the question. Are you asking specifically about the increase in the use of the word in the second of the two senses?

Comment: @jsw29 - mainly the second, but I suppose also the first, one, too. They seem related enough to me.

Answer (score 1):

**I guess** in the sense "I suppose" dates from the late 14th century per attestations in the MED. If it is prevalent, I guess it's because people prefer to say "I suppose" to saying "I have no (effing) clue and I don't really care" or "I'm damn certain". It is somewhat polite.